# create table using select statement in place of table_name

Tags: sql, sql-server

create table using select statement in place of table_name.

I want to create a table with the name B100 where '100' is the maximum value of id in table 'A'

example:

table A:

```
id  name
100 harsh
78  Vishal
23  Ivan
34  Hardik
```

need to create table with name 'B{max_value_of_id_in_A}'.

the fields in table B is the same (id, name);

what I try:

```
create table CONCAT('B', (Select max(id) from A)) 
(
id int,
name varchar(50)
)
```

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: This is most certainly an [XY Problem](http://xyproble.info). What problem are you *really* trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to use dynamic sql. A quick and dirty example is:

```
create table test(id smallint, name varchar(15));
insert test (id, name) values
(98, 'harsh'), (78, 'Vishal'), (23, 'Ivan'), (34, 'Hardik');

declare @sql nvarchar(200);

set @sql = N'create table B' + format((select max(id) from test), 'D3')
+ N'(
    id int,
    name varchar(50)
);'

select @sql;
exec(@sql);
exec('select * from B098');
```

Notice that I had to resort to dynamic sql to actually use that table within the same batch. As the others have suggested, you should reconsider the path you have chosen for many reasons. Perhaps foremost is that this requires a rather advanced level of skill - you will likely need much help to make use of your table. You should consult with your DBA to get their opinion (and permission).